# surface integral

Tags: symbols

I can do a path integral like this:

```
$$\oint \limits_{C(S)} fd{\textbf l}$$
```

But how can I do a surface integral?  The output should look something the surface integrals below, but hopefully better:

[image]

Comment: this question gives a general method for identifying symbols: [How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/579)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A version where the limits are *underneath* the integral signs:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,esint}

\newcommand*\VF[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand*\dif{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \iiint\limits_V (\nabla \cdot \VF{F}) \dif V
  &= \oiint\limits_{S(V)} \VF{F} \cdot \hat{\VF{n}} \dif S\\
  \iiint\limits_V (\nabla \times \VF{F}) \dif V
  &= \oiint \hat{\VF{n}} \times \VF{F} \dif S
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output1]

A version where the limits are *beside* the integral signs:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,esint}

\newcommand*\VF[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand*\dif{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \iiint_{V} (\nabla \cdot \VF{F}) \dif V
  &= \oiint_{S(V)} \VF{F} \cdot \hat{\VF{n}} \dif S\\
  \iiint_{V} (\nabla \times \VF{F}) \dif V
  &= \oiint \hat{\VF{n}} \times \VF{F} \dif S
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

Note: As pointed out by Charles Staats, the upright `d` in a differential is not common notation in all branches of science; for an italic `d`, simply use a `d` without `\mathrm`.

Comment: If the name clash occurs, the compiler will warn you unless you use `\def` instead of `\(re)newcommand`.

Comment: A note: Depending on your field, it may or may not be desirable to make the `d` in e.g. `dV` upright (as in this answer) rather than the default italic. To get italic, simply replace `\mathrm{d}` by `d` in the definition of the `\dif` command; the command is still useful to adjust the spacing.

Comment: @CharlesStaats In general I'd completely agree, but style seemed to be unimportant; I was merely trying to replicate the given example as closely as I could.  (Personally, I'd define an `\Int<n>_^[d-var]{integrand}` macro for this.)  I will say that I've never seen a field that prefers an italicized `d` (although I have seen it in a `\mathbb`-like style).

Comment: @Sean: An italicized `d` is preferred in pure mathematics.

Comment: @CharlesStaats How odd… not in my experience!  Notation tends to differ with geography as well… Strange.

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,esint}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \iiint\limits_V(\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F}) dV
      & = \oiint \limits_{S(V)} \mathbf{F \cdot \hat{n}} dS \\
  \iiint\limits_V(\nabla \times \mathbf{F}) dV
      & = \oiint \limits_{S(V)} \mathbf{\hat{n} \times F} dS \\
  \iiint\limits_V(\nabla f) dV
      & = \oiint\limits_{S(V)}\mathbf{\hat{n}}f dS
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Don't you need to load the `amsmath` packages to get the `align` environment?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg You are absolutely right; I'm not sure why it worked on my system without that…

Comment: [continuation from below Svend's answer] The first three books I checked were Ahlfors' *Complex Analysis*, Spivak's *Comprehensive Introduction*, and the calculus book I'm teaching out of (Stewart, *Multivariable Calculus*). All three of them use italicized `d` for differentials. I also just confirmed that Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry* and Beauville's *Complex Algebraic Surfaces* use italicized `d`. I don't want to waste too much time on this, but of the five books on my bookshelf I have checked, all five of them used an italicized `d` for differentials.